# How do i filter core data items by date?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, ios14

I am trying to display data saved to Core Data on a specific date which is selected by the user via a DatePicker.

The data is saved as below with .date:

```
func saveBreakfast() {
        
        
        let newBreakfastItem = BreakfastItem(context: self.moc)
        newBreakfastItem.id = UUID()
        newBreakfastItem.name = self.item.name
        newBreakfastItem.calories = Int32(self.totalCalories)
        newBreakfastItem.carbs = Int32(self.totalCarbs)
        newBreakfastItem.protein = Int32(self.totalProtein)
        newBreakfastItem.fat = Int32(self.totalFats)
        newBreakfastItem.date = self.dateAdded

        
        
        
        do {
        if self.mocB.hasChanges { // saves only if changes are made
        try? self.mocB.save()
            
            }
            
        }
}
```

I currently have

```
@State var selectedDate : Date
```

&

```
ForEach(self.BreakfastItems.filter { $0.date == selectedDate }, id: \.id) { newBreakfastItems in
```

However nothing is displaying, any idea why this is? are the two dates not formatted correctly?

Or is there another way this could be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some remarks:
- You use a different managed object context to create the Entity and a different one to save it (moc, mocB)
- How do you fetch the entities you saved? You could use a predicate in the fetch instead of a filter.
- If you do not use it elsewhere, the variable "id" is unnecessary, as in Entities using \ .self is fine.

Comment: It is better to filter by CoreData not in view-rendering time, because you will soon meet performance issues.

Comment: @NikosPolychronakis  Im using a different context for each meal (mocB, mocL, mocD, mocS -> Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, Snacks)) so that was a mistake, however moc was still saving as Ive used that previously for general food items. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Asperi noted thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function to load breakfast items at a specific date from Core Data:

```
    func loadBreakfastItemsFromCoreData(at date: Date) -> [BreakfastItems] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<BreakfastItems> = BreakfastItems.fetchRequest()

        let startDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(date)
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.day = 1
        components.second = -1
        let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: startDate)!

        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate, endDate) 
        // Optional: You can sort by date
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
        do {
            return try mocB.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from context: \(error)")
        }
        return []
    }
```

If you are using different contexts, make sure you know how to do that. If you don't know, read about it, or simply use one context. In my example, I used your background context, but feel free to switch to the main context.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this problem has been an issue for a while and this function has helped me solve it!